# Best method in Magento1 to set search URL's to be no index and no follow

Tags: catalogsearch

Looking at Magento1 catalog internal search

Would adding the below to the search file template be the best method to stop URL's indexing in search engines?

NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW

Any other ways to do?

Comment: I think this might be solution here - https://gist.github.com/jasontipton/9e35ae3f878282ba37ae  But yet to test.